# What is an example of a word hyperbolic group without a finite complete rewriting system?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I believe that it was an open question back when I was a graduate student whether every word hyperbolic group admits a finite complete (=Church-Rosser=Noetherian+confluent) rewriting system for some finite generating set.

I am basically wondering if this question is still open, and if not what is the counterexample. (I find it hard to believe that every word hyperbolic group does have a finite complete rewriting system but would be happy also if somebody has proven this.)

The only necessary conditions I know for having a finite complete rewriting system are solvable word problem and $FP_{\infty}$.

Comment: I do not think there is an example. As a candidate, I would take the intermediate groups in the construction of a free Burnside group.

Comment: By the way, every hyperbolic group has a complete rewriting system "at 1", i.e. a finite rewriting system which is terminating and confluent at 1: if $u=1$, and $u\to v, u\to w$, then $v\to 1, w\to 1$. Take all words of length $\le 100\delta$ that are equal to 1. For each such word $w$ include all relations $u\to v$ where $u$ is a subword of $w$, $|u|> 1/2|w|$, $v$ is the complement of $u$ in $w$ (considered as a cyclic word). Derek Holt probably knows examples when that rewriting system is not complete (in general).

Comment: @MarkSapir, is such a rewriting system complete for surface groups?

Comment: For surface groups, there is another complete rewriting system - by Susan Hermiller (see my book). Whether this one is confluent, I do not know, never thought about it. I think Susan or Derek Holt must know.

Comment: It was that example in your book that prompted this question.

Comment: @Mark: Your Dehn algorithm example cannot be complete in general, because it is strictly length reducing. In the (silly) example $\langle x,y \mid x=y \rangle$, $x$ and $y$ would be irreducible words representing the same group element. But I don't even know if there is an example of a hyperbolic group with given generating set for which it is known that there is no finite complete rewriting system. There may be examples if we fix the generating set and insist that the rewriting system is length non-increasing.

Comment: A personal feel is that if you manage to find an example admitting (infinite) complete rewriting system, the LHS of the rules forming context-free non-regular language, then most definitely the group will not admit a finite complete system. Note that, even wrt to the same generating set though sometimes it's possible to find another infinite complete system with LHS forming a regular language